# Passing Perl variable to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, perl

**Problem**
I am getting errors when passing a Perl variable to a Javascript function. Am I missing something?

> ```
> print "<button onclick='return getPdf("$user");'>PDF</button>";
> ```
>
> Results in error: **POST page.pl 500 (Internal Server Error)**
>
> ```
> print "<button onclick='return getPdf(".$user.");'>PDF</button>";
> ```
>
> Results in error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Tom is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (page.pl:113)**
>
> ```
> print "<button onclick='return getPdf('$user');'>PDF</button>";
> ```
>
> Results in error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**
>
> ```
> print "<button onclick='return getPdf('.$user.');'>PDF</button>";
> ```
>
> Results in error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

**page.pl**

```
$user = "Tom";
print "<button onclick='return getPdf();'>PDF</button>";
```

**Javascript**

```
function getPdf(user) {
    alert("User is: " + user);
}
```

Comment: Try using using the `q(...)` function for quoting as in  `q|<button> onclick='return getPdf(| . $user . q|);'>PDF</button>|;`

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

Comment: Replaced:
print "<button onclick='return getPdf("$user");'>PDF</button>"; 

With: q|<button onclick='return getPdf(| . $user . q|);'>PDF</button>|;

The button doesnt even appear now

Comment: try ikegami's suggestion

Comment: I found the solution!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is the fix**

Surround the variable that needs to be passed into a function with the following:

```
\''.$variable.'\'
```

Complete code:

```
print '<button onclick="return getPdf(\''.$user.'\');">PDF</button>';
```

Comment: This codes suffers from both a JavaScript code injection bug and an HTML code injection bug!!! (See [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).) For example, that fails if `$user` contains `'`, `\ `, `&` or `"`. `$user` probably doesn't contain those, but I'm sure `$user` is not the only variable, so giving a solution that's specific to `$user` isn't useful.

Answer (score -1):

You are asking how to convert text into a JavaScript literal, and how to embed that JavaScript literal into HTML.

This can done quite simply with the following:

```
print '<button onclick="return getPdf('.text_to_html(text_to_jslit($user)).');">PDF</button>';
```

Sample implementation of `text_to_html`:

```
{
   my %translations = (
      '&' => '&amp;',
      '<' => '&lt;',
      '>' => '&lt;',
      '"' => '&quot;',
      "'" => '&apos;',
   );

    my $meta_chars_class = join '', map quotemeta, sort keys %translations;
    my $meta_chars_re = qr/([$meta_chars_class])/;

   sub text_to_html { $_[0] =~ s/$meta_chars_re/$translations{$1}/rg }
}
```

Sample implementation of `text_to_jslit`:

```
{
   my @js_line_terminators = ( 0x000A, 0x000D, 0x2028, 0x2029 );

   my @control_chars = ( 0x00..0x1F, 0x7F..0x9F );  # Incomplete, but optional anyway.

   my %translations = (
      ( map { chr($_) => sprintf($_ <= 0xFF ? "\\x%02x" : "\\u%04x", $_) }
         @js_line_terminators,
         @control_chars,
         ord('<'),          # To prevent </script> from appearing literally.
      ),

      # More readable escapes.
      "\x08" => '\\b',
      "\x09" => '\\t',
      "\x0A" => '\\n',
      "\x0B" => '\\v',
      "\x0C" => '\\f',
      "\x0D" => '\\r',

      '"'  => '\\"',
      '\\' => '\\\\',
    );

    my $meta_chars_class = join '', map quotemeta, sort keys %translations;
    my $meta_chars_re = qr/([$meta_chars_class])/;

    sub text_to_jslit { '"'.( $_[0] =~ s/$meta_chars_re/$translations{$1}/rg ).'"' }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This looks quite complicated for just passing a Perl variable to a js function

Comment: You're not asking to how to pass a value to a function; you're asking how to generate JS code, and you're along how to generate HTML.

Comment: How exactly do I implement these two implementations? Are they supposed to be functions? I am not too familiar with Perl, I apologise

Comment: Huh? As you say yourself,  I already provided implementations

Comment: So I am supposed to copy paste these two implementation sections into my perl page? I am receiving an error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: It is not loading the page at all. Page output: "Please try again later". Chrome console output: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Yeah, so what error did the script give? 500 just tells you the script didn't return a response. Gotta check the logs for error messages!

Comment: Not too sure where I can find that

Comment: I got the solution. Not too sure whether I stated my question wrongly or you just gave me a very complex answer.

Comment: @Andrie, Complex problems often require "complex" solutions.  Yours is buggy.